# FizzBuzz example in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, fizzbuzz

Working through some JS examples and I wrote this solution for a fizzbuzz question. It just prints 1..20 and `str` never gets the `concat()` value. **Can someone please explain why this doesn't work?**

```
for(i=1; i<=20; i++){
    var str = ''
    if(i%3===0){     
        str.concat('Fizz')
    }
    if(i%5===0){
        str.concat('Buzz')
    }
    if(str===''){
        console.log(i)
    } else {
        console.log(str)
    }
}
```

Update: Since the above question was a simple syntax error (don't want to start a new thread), **was wondering if the following is good way to write the above answer succinctly in JS**?

```
for(i=1; i<=20; i++){
    var str = ''
    i%3===0 ? str = str.concat('Fizz') : false
    i%5===0 ? str = str.concat('Buzz') : false
    str==='' ?  console.log(i) : console.log(str)
}
```

Comment: Strings are immutable in Javascript. You always have to assign the result of a string operation.

Comment: I just realized the problem/solution and already you guys returned the answer. Thanks. I need to get out of my Ruby frame of mind when in JS.

Comment: The only mutable types in JS are objects and arrays.

Comment: @cdlane You necro'd a thread just to add a tag?

Comment: @MichaelL. Yes, there are too many new fizzbuzz questions that could easily be answered by existing ones (more untagged than tagged in this case.)  Will pause and consider your comment, however.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `String.prototype.concat()` returns contatenated string.

You need to do `str = str.concat("XYZ");`

Answer (score 0):

`str.concat` RETURNS the new string. It doesn't modify the original one. Try

```
str = str.concat('Fizz');
```

Answer (score 0):

A more consize solution

```
const fizzbuzz = num => {
  let str; 
  for(let i=1; i<=num; i++) {
    str = "";
    if(i%3===0) {
      str = "fizz";
    }
    if(i%5===0) {
      str += "buzz";
    }
    console.log(str || i);
  }
}

fizzbuzz(100);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var output = [];
var count = 1;

function fizzBuzz(){ 
     if(count % 3 === 0 && count % 5 === 0){
        output.push("FizzBuzz");
     }else if(count % 3 === 0){
        output.push("Fizz");
    }else if(count % 5 ===0){
        output.push("Buzz");
    }else{
       output.push(count); 
    }
    count++;
console.log(output);    
}
fizzBuzz();
```

Comment: You should REALLY prefer using a static variable for `count`unless you have a very good reason not to